# Push Data To Client Using SignalR

Tags: signalr

I'm sorry for potentially creating a duplicate thread here, but I simply cannot get my web application to do what I need by following the other examples I've found.

My goal is to do one of the following:

**OPTION 1 - IDEAL SOLUTION**
Fetch data from a database and update the UI on a web page ONLY when changes are made to the data being displayed on the web page. For example, if a user is viewing a service ticket, I don't want to update the UI on that page unless that ticket is changed.

**OPTION 2 - ACCEPTABLE SOLUTION**
Fetch data from a database every x seconds and use that data to update the UI on a web page.

My current implementation of **Option 2** is below. It involves sending an asynchronous HTTP request every 60 seconds to fetch the data:

```
// start checking for new messages every 60 seconds
setInterval(function () {
    $.ajax({
        async: true,
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8;",
        url: "/AJAX_Handlers/CheckForNewMessages.ashx",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (Result) {
            var new_message_received = Result[0]["NewMessageReceived"];

            if (new_message_received) {
                $("#DIVMessageReminder").html("<strong>You have " + num_new_messages + " new message(s).</strong>");
                $("#DIVMessageReminder").show();
            }
            else {
                $("#DIVMessageReminder").hide();
            }
        }
    });
}, 60000);
```

Rather than sending an HTTP request every 60 seconds, I would like to use SignalR to push that data to the client every 60 seconds.

As a simple example, I have created the following Hub with a method to get the current time on the server:

```
Imports Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR

Public Class ServerTimeHub
    Inherits Hub

    Public Sub GetServerTime()
        Dim current_time As String = Now.ToString()
        Clients.All.updateTime(current_time)
    End Sub

End Class
```

And a basic textbox:

```
<input id="TXTLongPollingTest" type="text" class="form-control" />
```

And my client-side code:

```
var hub = $.connection.serverTimeHub;

hub.client.updateTime = function (new_time) {
    $("#TXTLongPollingTest").val(new_time);
}

$.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
    alert("connected to the SignalR hub");
    hub.getServerTime();
}).fail(function (err) {
    alert("failed to connect to SignalR hub: " + err);
});
```

At first I tried getting it to fetch the server time just once. My code will successfully connect to the hub, but then it throws an error saying "Uncaught TypeError: hub.getServerTime is not a function". That's the first problem I haven't been able to overcome.

The second problem is: How can I get the hub to send the current time to the client on a regular interval such as every 1 second?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I have done to achieve something similar. Essentially fetching data from the database and broadcasting to clients every 30 seconds.

In my global.asax.cs I have this to ensure whenever my website is has started/restarted it will kick off my repeater:

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GetTeamData.TeamDataRepeater();
}
```

In my GetTeamData.cs I have a timer that is set to run every 30 seconds

```
public class GetTeamData
  {    
    static Timer TeamDataTimer = new Timer();

    public static void TeamDataRepeater()
    {
          TeamDataTimer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent_TeamDataBroadcaster);
          TeamDataTimer.Interval = 30000; //30 Seconds
          TeamDataTimer.Start(); 
    }

    public static void OnTimedEvent_TeamDataBroadcaster(Object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
          updateFirstRow(); 
    }

    public static void updateFirstRow()
    {
          IHubContext hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<MsgHub>();
          hubContext.Clients.All.pushMyData(mydata1, mydata2, mydata3);
    }           

   }
```

My java script for the client has:

```
//I have already started my connection

$(function () {
    var chat = $.connection.msgHub;
    chat.client.pushMyData = function (mydata1, mydata2, mydata3)
    {
    //Do something with the returned data now
    }
});
```

Note that I have removed some things such as use of try/catch just to give you an example.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Even though this seems to be very similar to all the other examples out there, this has worked for me. Thank you so much for your help!  I would still like to know if anyone has a solution for fetching new data ONLY when the data in question has been changed.